# 1 byte integer doesn't convert i/o formats

Tags: c++, hex, uint, iomanip

I wrote the code below which inputs a number in hex format and outputs it in decimal form:-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<stdint.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  uint8_t c;
  cin>>hex>>c;
  cout<<dec<<c;
  //cout<<sizeof(c);
  return 0;
}
```

But when I input c(hex for 12), the output was again c(and not 12). Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `uint8_t` is usually a `typedef` for `unsigned char`.  So it's actually reading `'c'` as ASCII `0x63`.

Use `int` instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int c;
    cin>>hex>>c;
    cout<<dec<<c<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
$ g++ test.cpp
$ ./a.out
c
12
```

Comment: @dietrich...so is there a way in which i can input a 1 byte data into in hex format into an 1 byte integer and it behaves as integer and not char

Comment: Go ahead and click "Ask Question" at the top.

Answer (score 4):

This is an unfortunate side effect of the fact that `uint8_t` is actually `unsigned char`. So when you store c, its storing the ASCII value of c (99 decimal), not the numeric value 12.

Answer (score 0):

`uint8_t` is an alias of `unsigned char` and unfortunately `ostream` tries to output it as a character. This has been fixed in C++20 [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format):

```
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
  uint8_t n = 42;
  std::cout << std::format("{}", n);
}
```

Output:

```
42
```